# Why does lodash.isError need to exist?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lodash offers a method called [_.isError](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isError). Why do we need to use that method instead of `val instanceof Error`?

If you look at the source, you'll see:

```js
    function isError(value) {
      if (!isObjectLike(value)) {
        return false;
      }
      var tag = baseGetTag(value);
      return tag == errorTag || tag == domExcTag ||
        (typeof value.message == 'string' && typeof value.name == 'string' && !isPlainObject(value));
    }
```

I am not sure what cases this complexity handles that `val instanceof Error` does not.

Comment: It's just another convenience method. See the [source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L11592).

Comment: @Phix but why is the convenience method [78 lines](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.1.1-npm-packages/lodash.iserror/index.js) when there's a single expression that seemingly does just as well?

Comment: @NickHeiner the source is 78 lines if you include all the comments. It's really just less than 20 lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit contrived, but here is where `_.isError(val)` and `val instanceof Error` diverge:

(assume `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>` is in the html)

```
function Foo() {
    this.message="a";
    this.name="a";
}
_.isError(new Foo) // true
new Foo instanceof Error // false
```

I cannot say if this is intended behavior on their part, but this is where the lodash method handles extra complexity.

Comment: To me, this looks more like yet another reason why `isError` shouldn’t exist. Seems buggy, but thankfully this should be rare to accidentally happen